Reference Assignment in C#
I'm debugging a code example and I'm confused at how variables are assigned. In Add(), on the first pass it assigns _first equal to _last because _first is null. After the first call to Add(), _last is not null so it assigns the new node value to _last.Next. because _first points to _last (from the first pass), both _first.Next and _last.Next are updated. What confuses is me is why  _last = t; only updates _last and not _first.
public class QueueCustom<T>
{
    public class QueueNode<T>
    {
        public T Data;
        public QueueNode<T>? Next;

        public QueueNode(T data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }
    }

    private QueueNode<T>? _first;
    private QueueNode<T>? _last;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var t = new QueueNode<T>(item);

        if (_last != null)
        {
            _last.Next = t; // both first and last are pointing to the same node, both _first and _last Next properties get updated
        }

        _last = t; // _last is now pointing to the new node but why doesn't _first point to the new node as well?

        _first ??= _last;
    }

    public T Remove()
    {
        if (_first == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");
        }

        T data = _first.Data;
        _first = _first.Next;

        if (_first == null)
        {
            _last = null;
        }

        return data;
    }
}

Call:
var queue = new QueueCustom<int>();
queue.Add(1);
queue.Add(2);
queue.Add(3);

Why is this happening?

@topsail, correct, good catch. I've updated it.


What confuses is me is why _last = t; only updates _last and not _first.

Well it's only assigning to _last... so only _last is affected. Just because at some point you have (effectively) _first = _last doesn't mean the two variables are forever bound together - it just says "evaluate the expression _last, and set the value of _first to be the result of that evaluation".
As a much simpler example:
string x = "initial x";
string y = "initial y";
y = x;
x = "new x";
Console.WriteLine(y); // This prints "initial x"

Here, the third line says "What's the current value of x? Make that the new value of y." They're just values. It doesn't mean "make y an alias for x". So when the value of x is changed on line 4, that doesn't affect y at all.
If that doesn't help, you may want to read my "references and values" article, or my answer to a related question.

Hi @jon, your example makes sense. What confuses me is the line _first ??= _last;  sets _first as a reference to _last . So on the next Add() call  _last.Next = t; updates both _last.Next and _first.Next . But what prevents the _last = t; line from updating _first?

after _first ??= _last;, assuming _first was null, means that _first and _last will now refer to the same QueueNode, which is an object (on the heap, probably). Its not like pointers in C (or a pointer to a pointer? - my C is very rusty) so _first does not refer to _last, rather _first and _last both refer to the same QueueNode. Later when you re-assign _last.Next to refer to a new QueueNode, you have not done anything at all to _first - it still refers to the same QueueNode as it did before, and its .Next property still refers to the same QueueNode as it did before as well.

@Josh "_first ??= _last; sets _first as a reference to _last" - no, it doesn't. It copies the current value of _last into _first. That's all it does. That value is a reference to a QueueNode. If you change the value of _last to a different reference later, that doesn't affect _first at all.
